# c++ assign value to a const QList in if... else

Tags: c++, constants, variable-assignment, conditional-statements, const-correctness

I would like to assign a value to a `const QList` depending on the value of a pointer.

`invar` is a pointer, if it is `NULL` I want to assign a first value to `const QList mylist`, if it is not `NULL`, another value. But const correctness is observed: i do not intend to change value for `mylist` afterwards.

Is it possible to have

```
if(invar)
    const QList<Type> zoneList = invar->getZones();
else
    const QList<Type> zoneList = aList ;
```

I am defining `zoneList` once exactly, so why would this not be working ?

ALso, as I am using `zoneList` in the next part of my method, I get this compile error: `undeclared identifier`.

But I am not allowed to write that either

```
    const QList<Type> zoneList ;

    if(invar)
        zoneList = invar->getZones();
    else
        zoneList = NULL ;
```

and I have compiler error Error 1

```
error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const QList<T>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Is it possible to have two different values assigned to this const QList depending on a condition ? What is the right way to write it then ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the ternary operator `?:`

```
const QList<Type> zoneList(invar ? invar->getZones() : aList);
```

BTW is it `NULL` or is it `aList`? You have both in your code above.

This

```
if(invar)
    const QList<Type> zoneList = invar->getZones();
else
    const QList<Type> zoneList = aList ;
```

doesn't work because each zoneList variable is defined inside the if statement only.

Answer (score 5):

With such a simple condition, you could just use the ternary operator:

```
const QList<Type> zoneList = invar ? invar->getZones() : aList;
```

If the initialization gets more complex than that and you happen to use C++11, then you can use a new idiom made possible by lambdas:

```
const QList<Type> zoneList = [] () -> QList<Type> {
                          // ^^ possibly [&] to capture variables

        // some complex stuff that returns a QList<Type>

    }(); // Note the () that calls the lambda immediately
```

If you are stuck with C++03 (or, Stroustrup forbid, C++98), there are few solutions left except calling another function/method, with the drawback that you have to pass as a parameter any local variable you need to compute the const value.

---

**Edit:** I realize I haven't fully answered your question. Others have already explained that your first `if` can't work because it's a matter of scope, I won't add much except that adding braces will probably make it clearer for you (note how this is strictly the same code as yours: the braces are optional when the `if`/`else` bodies are just a single statement but their presence/absence doesn't change the semantics of the code):

```
if (invar) {
    const QList<Type> zoneList = invar->getZones();
}
else {
    const QList<Type> zoneList = aList;
}
```

Comment: Nice use case of a lambda.

Comment: @leemes: Yeah I discovered it not long ago (on H.Sutter's blog I believe) and it struck me as a very nice solution to that old problem. Since then, I try to spread it whenever the topic arises. ;)

Comment: Actually in our current project at work, we use a lot const smart pointers, but when creating a new object and setting attributes on that, it should not (yet) be const, yet we have to return a const pointer or continue some next step with a const pointer. Our current "nicest-we-can-get" solution is to first keep the pointer non-const and non-smart and "wrap" it only in the return statement / as soon as it should be const. It will make a nice improvement when I integrate your solution in such cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
if(invar)
    const QList<Type> zoneList = invar->getZones();
else
    const QList<Type> zoneList = aList ;
```

the scope of `zoneList` is limited to the `if` or `else` branch, and outside it does not exist anymore.
And if you do

```
const QList<Type> zoneList ;

if(invar)
    zoneList = invar->getZones();
else
    zoneList = NULL ;
```

`zoneList` is declared `const` and cannot be changed in `if`/`else`.

For a hack you could use `const_cast`, but it is bad practice so you must initialize `zoneList`.

```
zoneList = invar != 0 ? invar->getZones() : 0; //don't use NULL in C++
```